# MySQL distinct doesn't return Distinct Values

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have a strange MySQL question. For some reason my query is not returning distinct values. As it should.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(market_devices.deviceId), 
               market_devices.id, 
               registerId, 
               deviceOs 
FROM   market_devices_link 
       INNER JOIN market_devices 
               ON market_devices_link.deviceId = market_devices.id 
WHERE  market_devices_link.shopid = '46' 
       AND ( market_devices.deviceId IS NOT NULL 
             AND market_devices.registerId IS NOT NULL)
       AND market_devices.registerId NOT LIKE 'NO_NOTIFICATION%';
```

With this query I'm getting 9 results with 3 times the deviceId = '356150053892215';

Rewriting the query to a GROUP BY market_devices.DeviceId will result in 7 values without duplicate deviceIds. (see Query below)

```
SELECT market_devices.id, 
               registerId, 
               deviceos 
FROM   market_devices_link 
       INNER JOIN market_devices 
               ON market_devices_link.deviceId = market_devices.id 
WHERE  market_devices_link.shopid = '46' 
       AND ( market_devices.deviceId IS NOT NULL 
             AND market_devices.registerId IS NOT NULL)
       AND market_devices.registerId NOT LIKE 'NO_NOTIFICATION%'
GROUP BY market_devices.deviceId;
```

We are having a performance issue as well, so what would be a better approach? Bear in mind that we only need 1 item per distinct DeviceId. Would DISTINCT or GROUP BY be a better approach?

Comment: DISTINCT is applied to the entire row, not to only one column. That's why you need to use GROUP BY. As for performance problems, please refer to similar questions on SO, it boils down to optimizing MySQL's settings (you didn't specify whether you've done so), analysing the query with EXPLAIN etc.

Comment: The DISTINCT optimizes for memory usage: it would still perform reasonably well when part of the temporary table has to be swapped out. The GROUP BY optimizes for speed, but potentially requires a large amount of memory if there are a lot of different keys. Follow other answers on SO.